# Pass values for drop-down from business layer, what is best practices?

Tags: c#, architecture

Usually I use the following class to fill dropdowns or lists on the form:

```
class DisplayValue
{
    string Display { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
    bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

the question: is it good solution if List of DisplayValue comes from BusinessLayer? People say "Business Layer should return business objects like Person, Invoice, Contract. But presentation layer should prepare ViewModel.". In this case we are doomed to query extra data from DB. For example I need dropdown with the following text "FirstName LastName, TotalAmount". In this case I doomed to query from BL list of Persons and List of invoices for each person to build List of DisplayValue in controller.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider adding a method in the BL something like GetNamesAndInvoiceTotal(). You should do all the logic for summing up invoices etc there. Prevents polluting the presentation layer and makes it clear what its for. But you need to be careful you are not making your BL return a `DisplayValue` class if a better structure is more appropriate, just because its what you do elsewhere.